# Disable the Selection/Check box When the other one is Selected/Checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code looks like this, what i want is when the use clicked on the Current time check box then disable the time selection bar, when the user select something in the selection bar, disable the current time check box, i know this is achievable but i don't know how to do it, I tired some ways but non of them works, please tell me how i can do it no matter by JavaScript or CSS, Thank you very much

```
 Enter travel time <input type="time" name="usr_time">   
 Use current time  <input type = "checkbox" name = "Currenttime" value = "Currenttime">
```

Comment: jQuery version: `$('[name="Currenttime"]').on('change',function(){ $('[name="usr_time"]').prop('disabled',this.checked); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
function checkControl(){
    if(Currenttime.checked === false){
        usr_time.disabled = false;
    }else{
        usr_time.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d3bw9wcd/)

Also note that `id` attribute have been added to both elements so that their properties can be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `document.querySelector` with `attribute` selector to select the
  target elements.
- `addEventListener` to attach `change` event on `check-box` element.
- `disabled` property to `disable` to `user_time` element.
- `this.checked` will be current state of the `check-box` element.

---

```js
document.querySelector('[name="Currenttime"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('[name="usr_time"]').disabled = this.checked;
});
```

```html
Enter travel time
<input type="time" name="usr_time">Use current time
<input type="checkbox" name="Currenttime" value="Currenttime">
```